# CGridView encoded the value

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I'm following the documents here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/

So I have the following in view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'item-table-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'itemsCssClass'=>'item-table-grid',
'columns'=>array(
    'customer_name',
    array(
        'name'=>'Edit',
        'value'=>array($model, 'editLink'),
    ),
),
));
```

And here is the editLink function in model

```
public function editLink($data, $row) {
    $link = '';
    if ($data->is_draft) {
        $link = '<a href="customer/update/'.$data->id.'">Edit</a>';
    }
    return $link;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the return value is encoded so I get <a href=...>

Is there a way to tell CGridView not to encode the value?

Thanks

Comment: basically you can encode/decode it at view level but that doesn't seems to be the best choice.

<?php echo CHtml::encode($link); ?>

Comment: It came out as encoded and i dont like to use decode, i prefer to have it not encoded in the first place. Setting type to raw seems to do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution A:

```
array(
    'name'=>'Edit',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value'=>array($model, 'editLink'),
),
```

B: (not good enough)

```
array(
    'name' => 'Edit',
    'class' => 'CLinkColumn',
    'urlExpression' => '$data->is_draft ? "customer/update/{$data->id}" : "#disabled"',
    'label' => 'edit',
),
```

Comment: I prefer the Solution A because I need to handle special case in the model. Setting the type to raw did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this ..

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'item-table-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'itemsCssClass'=>'item-table-grid',
'columns'=>array(
    'customer_name',
    array(
'name'=>'Edit',
'type' => 'raw',
'value'=>array($model, 'editLink'),
```

), 
    ),
    ));

Comment: That works! Thanks. Sorry I can't pick two answers. Both two answers here are good.

Answer (score 0):

```
my code in CGridView

array(
        'name'=>'Post Content',
        'value'=>array($model,'postContent'),
        'type'=>'html',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'380'),
    ),

in Model I have the following method

public function postContent($data){
    echo $data->content;
}

 it works fine but when i click on another page of my pagination
then it doesn't works means it work only on Index page first time opened...

plz any solution....???
```